# Is there only temporary permission for files shared from via default "Downloads" app?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-fileprovider

I try to play audio file after user select/share audio file in some file browser. To do this I use filter intent through which I get Uri of audio file. Based on Uri I can play it. Uri is used by MediaPlayer to open FileDescriptor.

I store Uri so I can use it after app is restarted. It works with all file browsers except android's default Downloads app. If I open file from Downloads app I receive Uri like this:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/25 - on android 7
```

I can play it. But after app is restarted, I can't play same uri anymore. I get exception:

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from 
ProcessRecord{160760b 3618:com.sample/u0a71} (pid=3618, uid=10071) 
requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
```

from [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MANAGE_DOCUMENTS) about this permission:

> This permission should only be requested by the platform document
>   management app. This permission cannot be granted to third-party apps.

Does it mean that app has only temporary permission for file? Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out that sender app set only temporary permission using these flags `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. Permission is valid only as long as activity which handled intent is active.
So at least to detect this I use

```
if ((flags & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) == Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION || (flags & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRTITE_URI_PERMISSION) == Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION) {
//only temporary permission
}
```

Comment: I didn't know the permission is valid only as long as activity which handled the intent is active. Tried redirecting the intent to another Activity, which failed and couldn't figure out why.